# How tight should baseboards be for laminate?

Tags: basement, baseboard, laminate-floor, laminate

So, I'm a little stumped on this one.  I've installed laminate over a pad, but because of the way that the boards click in and the fact that it's a floating floor, the parts that end near the edges (particularly the last row that runs parallel to the wall) has a little bit of bounce to it.  Not really anywhere else, just the last row because it's not on a laser level subfloor (concrete basement) and the pad itself has some squish to it.

So the problem is, when you step on the last board it travels a little bit.  I can install the baseboard tight to the laminate (still allows it to slide under the baseboard for expansion), but even then it still produces a squeak with the subtle friction between the baseboard and the floor board.  I could install the baseboard loose, but then the last row would move up and down (which would be a little weird) and I'm guessing whould "whack" the base if I put it up too high.

What's the right way to do it?  Most instruction I see just say "nail your baseboard up and have a drink" and the ones that actually say anything usually say to keep the base tight (though many are for wood floors that don't flex so much).

Answer (score 1):

The last board is not secure to the wall ,and has plenty of movement - buy some talcum powder aka baby powder and place that under neath your floor boards and between the racks (joints) . It will act as a lubricant. Secure your baseboard tightly.

[Here is a link you can read more about it.](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/make-laminate-floor-stop-squeaking-47640.html)